# Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, nativescript

There is long time I had not developed any Android application (about 5 months) and now I have came back with nativescript. When I have created my first app using nativescript, I encountered this issue:

> Executing before-shouldPrepare hook from
>   C:\Data\ProjectFiles\NativeScript\HeavenlyMinutes\hooks\before-shouldPrepare\nativescript-dev-webpack.js
>   Skipping prepare. Building project... Gradle build...
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'HeavenlyMinutes'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
>   >     Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
>   >      Required by:
>   >          project :
>   >     Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
>   >     Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.
>   >     Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.
>   >     Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/108.168.243.150] failed: Connection timed out:
>   >     connect
>   >     Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
>   >     Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.
>   >     Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.
>   >     Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/108.168.243.150] failed: Connection timed out:
>   >     connect
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 48s Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1

So I have refered to my last projects created and developed using Android Studio. So the problem was there too. I have tested multiple configurations on gradle and for example two of them are mentioned below:

### One

gradle.wrapper.properties

```
#Thu Sep 27 11:34:03 EEST 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
```

build.gradle (project dependencies)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        gradlePluginPortal()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        gradlePluginPortal()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

### Two

gradle.wrapper.properties

```
   #Thu Sep 27 11:34:03 EEST 2018
    distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    distributionPath=wrapper/dists
    zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
    distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

build.gradle (project dependencies)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        gradlePluginPortal()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        gradlePluginPortal()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and none of them helped me. As my android projects were working before, I think the problem is somewhere else.

Note that the links https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.jar and https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom that are mentioned in the errors as unreachable links, are downloadable throw internet browser. So I think one possible solution will be to download them manually and put them somewhere in the project (but I have searched a lot how to do this and didn't find anything).

Comment: what is the CLI version you are using .. try to run tns update on the existing project so that it updates to latest version.

Comment: Hi ConductedClever. I notice from your post history that you sign your questions - please don't do that. It's noted in the Help Centre that we ask folks to refrain from signatures and greetings. In general, you posts are quite chatty and carry a certain pleading tone - if you can keep them succinct then there's less stuff to read, and you may get a better reception too.

Comment: @Baskar it is not about tns, but is about problem in fetching gradle package from `google()` repo.

Comment: Hi @halfer. Not exactly signs. by TG I meen something not signing the question. I need them in my notes for myself. I got your note. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your message to me, but please do not add them again, whatever they are. If you are in doubt as to whether they are permitted, I can find the relevant help page for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was all about sanctions. I have tried some sanction-breaker and at last [shecan](https://shecan.ir/) solved my issue.

This answer will be useful only for Iranian users.

Comment: Cubans also need that my friend,  how we can use shecan please?

Comment: I'm not pretty sure if shecan will work in your country or not, but in the website, a DNS Server is offered and it is enough to just configure your DNS configuration (on OS) to point this DNS Server. That's it. But I think this won't work in your country and you may ask shekan developers, to help you develop one for your people. I think this helps you.

Comment: hi im from iran and im using shecan(i have green message that you are using shecan in thier website) but still have problem to download requirement

Comment: May be you are using some proxies or vpns which are breaking the job. But I really don't know. I wish you could solve it.

Comment: Dude u totally solved my problem ...Thanks...Mamnun :D

Answer (score 0):

Finally, remove the proxy config in gradle.properties in .gradle folder, it words.Hope this answer will be useful.