# Android Studio - Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2

Tags: android, gradle

I just downloaded and attempted to build my first app using this as a guide:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project

The issue I am having is just about the same as this one:

[ERROR: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59150797/error-could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle3-5-2)

EDIT: My issue is identical to this one - [Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53837101/could-not-resolve-com-android-tools-buildgradle3-2-1)

Errors are below bottom. Also none of the suggestions in that post resolved this issue. I have also tried various combinations of offline and local cache as per other similar stackoverflow posts. Proxy settings are on "auto detect" and when pressing test connection and using goggle.com, its successful. My exact issue is a timeout when trying to retrieve .pom file. I can type in the location of the POM in a browser and I have downloaded the file without issue. I have it but not sure where to put it or if putting it will resolve the issue.

Gradle appears to be installed correctly in: C:\Users\xxxxx.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.4.1-all\3221gyojl5jsh0helicew7rwx

Gradle build file:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()

        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Errors:
Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2.

Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.2/gradle-3.5.2.pom'

Edit again: distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple, in this case. Even though I set the proxy to auto detect and test connection worked, proxy was still the issue. After pulling my hair out, I finally figured that I needed manual proxy config. The Host name kept causing an "Invalid Host Name" error, even though it was cut and pasted from my browser.

In proxy settings Manual proxy config in Android Studio:

Host Name: "http://myproxy.something" FAILS
 Host Name: "myproxy.something"  WORKS!!!!

After removing, the gradle error went away.